# Restrict access to channel to selected users within organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

We set up `Hyperledger Fabric` and added two `channels` (for two different applications). We also registered two `users` in our Organization (one for each application). We should restrict access to each `channel` so only the corresponding user can read and write based on `affiliation or OU` of the user.

We checked `Hyperledger Fabric` documentation on `channel policies` and did not find any indication on how to use `OU or affiliation` (i.e. conditions that go beyond "must be member of orgX").

From what I've read so far, I got the impression that restrictions within the organization can only be enforced in `chaincode`, but not by using policies (this is also indicated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056834/restrict-user-access-to-only-some-channels-in-hyperledger-fabric)).

**Is this really the way to go? Is there no possibility to restrict access to either a `OU` or an attribute like `affiliation` by just using the `channel policy`?**

Answer (score 0):

You can define an MSP that is [defined with the OU](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/sampleconfig/msp/config.yaml#L8) you have in mind, and then the user will have to belong to that MSP and use a certificate with that OU when it sends transactions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
We were hoping there was a possibility to use the `affiliation` that can be passed to the [`register` command](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#registering-a-new-identity). But since this does not seem to work, we will either try your solution or go on without further restricting user access to channels.